# Telerik UI for MAUI - How to remove "Dag a column header to group" message?

Tags: telerik, maui, telerik-grid

I'm using the Telerik UI for MAUI and getting this message appear at the top of my data tables.
[image]

Here is my telerik code for my data grids.

```
 <Grid Margin="20" >
        <!-- other controls or elements can be added here -->
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <telerik:RadDataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="dataGrid"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding myData}"
                     ShowGroupFooters="False"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding myData, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     GridLinesVisibility="Both">


            <telerik:RadDataGrid.RowBackgroundStyle>
                <telerik:DataGridBorderStyle BackgroundColor="LightCyan" 
                                 BorderColor="LightGray" 
                                 BorderThickness="2"/>
            </telerik:RadDataGrid.RowBackgroundStyle>
            <telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns >

                <telerik:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Description" HeaderText="Description"  SizeMode="Auto" >
                    
                    <telerik:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <telerik:DataGridColumnHeaderStyle BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                                               BorderColor="LightGray"
                                               BorderThickness="2" 
                                               TextFontSize="10"/>
                    </telerik:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <telerik:DataGridTextColumn.CellContentStyle>
                        <telerik:DataGridTextCellStyle                                        
                                        FontSize="10"                                      
                                         />
                    </telerik:DataGridTextColumn.CellContentStyle>

                </telerik:DataGridTextColumn>
           

            </telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        </telerik:RadDataGrid>
```

I have tried setting `ShowGroupPanel` to  `false`  but this does not work.

How can I remove  / disable this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Grouping UI in the grid. And the official document said:

> There are two ways to disable grouping. The first one is on a DataGrid level by using the UserGroupMode property. By setting it to Disabled the DataGridGroupingPanel gets hidden and the drag and drop function is disabled.

So you can use `<telerik:RadDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" UserGroupMode="Disabled">` in the xaml.

Or you can also try to use `CanUserGroup="False"` in the `DataGridTextColumn` such as:

```
<telerik:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Description" CanUserGroup="False" HeaderText="Description"  SizeMode="Auto" >.
```